# ANR problem in my app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I have quite a heavy Activity with a lot of things going on in the UI Thread, and also other Runnable threads within the Activity. Within this main activity I start a new Activity with a button press which is called using `startActivityForResult()`. Now when I start the new activity I get an ANR error meaning that there is something taking longer than the set amount of time and I get the ForceClose/Wait Dialog pop up.

The thing is, for the new Activity I am only setting the contentView for the activity and nothing else so it means something from the previous Activity is causing it to hang. It has never down this before in the app only recently and I can't think what I have added for it to cause this.

In the first Activity I have OpenFeint, SurfaceHolder.Callback, database calls in background thread and lot's of image manipulation. Are any of these processes hungry enough to cause the ANR?

Could I possibly put the first activity on hold while the second one loads (I thought it did that anyway)? Like I say the second Activity does nothing other than load a ContentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a new activity, the previous activity should be put on hold, as you say. But first the activity's onPause is called. Maybe it's this method which causes the ANR? Especially if it is saving large amounts of state data.

Just guessing here.

Comment: I'm going to give you the green tick, your answer helped me solve what was actually wrong. In the onStop method I had quite a few database and SharedPrefs calls and was trying to do these calls before moving to the next activity, I solved the problem by changing this to onDestroy as I only wanted to save this data when the app is fully closed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is an ANR it is pretty clear that something is running longer in the UI thread (as you have pointed out). Also, you seem to be doing a lot of things (at least the explanation gives this feeling). At this point I can say try commenting out certain parts and see if the problem persists. E.g. comment the startActivityForResult(), this should tell you which activity is the culprit. Also, if you can put up some pseudo code, I'm sure people would get a better idea and would be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

The ANR occurs usually when you solicit the UI (like pressing a button), so I think it's not the second activity launch which causes the ANR, but the fact you use the UI.

So the problem is from your first activity, not the second.